# Diffirent Paypal payment methods in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal

I am new to Magento. i need to test all Paypal payment methods in Magento. I want to know difference between all of these.
 [image]

When i click learn more link it is giving 404 page on Paypal. How do i configure this? How do i create sandbox account for this? Can i test sandbox in my local machine? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Create PayPal account use https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/home   Use sandbox credentials and just test

Comment: Can i use that crendentials for all paypal methods given in magento?